# Is $\mathbb{Z} ⊂ \mathbb{Q}$ true in formal proofs? How do formalized systems capture this relationship?

Tags: soft-question, formal-proofs, theorem-provers

Informally, mathematicians treat Integers like a subset of rational numbers.

But according to the standard, formal construction of $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{Q}$ is an equivalence class over $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}^∗$. So $0_Z \neq 0_Q$.

When mathematicians freely convert between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$, they are really making use of some canonical embedding $f : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ which maps $x$ to the equivalence class containing $(x, 1)$.

Mathematicians implicitly use these sorts of embeddings all of the time, and do not spend their time fiddling with the minutia. People do not care if their "integer" $x$ is in $\mathbb{Z}$ or in $f[\mathbb{Z}]$, and interchange between the two as-needed. For all intents and purposes these two sets are "equivalent".

Do any theorem provers handle these sorts of relationships gracefully? Are there systems/languages which support these intuitive equivalences and don't require humans to manually fiddle with and keep track of embeddings?

Comment: Gracefully? No.

Comment: It is trivial that every integer is rational , so this is a very boring true statement. It is also easy to see that $\mathbb Z$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb Q$ by considering , for example , $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: "some canonical embedding" is a funny turn of phrase. You want to disrespect it with "some" but have to admit: there can be only one ...

Comment: @Peter: I am afraid you are missing the point of this post, which is much more formal than the level you try to argue on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Coq](https://coq.inria.fr) has [coercions](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/implicit-coercions.html). You can define, say, a function `nat_to_int` which does whatever conversion is required for your implementation of natural and integer numbers and then declare `Coercion nat_to_int : nat >-> int`, which basically tells the interpreter "whenever you need an `int` but are given a `nat`, insert this function to convert." This is also often used to implicitly convert whatever algebraic structures, groups, monoids &c. you have formalized to their underlying sets (types), so you can say `x : G` when `G` is actually a tuple of a type, an operation on it, a specified unit element, an inverse function and a bunch of proofs of group laws for this structure.

Answer (score 1):

A "fugly" way to do it, in first-order logic + set theory, is to define the rationals using a preliminary definition:

$$ Q = \{ (k,n)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N} \}/\sim $$

where $(a,b)\sim (x,y)$ if $ay=bx$, and I am using $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\dots\}$ like any American mathematician. Then we "rip out" the natural numbers, identified as the subset:

$$ N = \{ (k, n)\in Q\mid \exists m\in\mathbb{N}, (m,1)\sim(k, n)\} $$

and "glue in" the natural numbers

$$ \mathbb{Q} = (Q \setminus N)\cup\mathbb{N}. $$

This is how [Mizar does it](http://mizar.uwb.edu.pl/version/current/html/arytm_3.html#K5), for example.